# If statement with a String input

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want make a if statement with a String input.

I have a MongoDB with Achievement data. This data contains a string with the condition that has to be met to get the achievement.

I want to use the condition (in String format) as the condition in an if statement.

I have the following code:

```
function checker(condition, achievementId, doc) {
  if((condition) && doc.Achievement.indexOf(achievementId) == -1) {
    return true 
} else {
    return false 
}
```

The doc is the data object that will get unlock the achievement.

makes sure the achievement isn't already unlocked.

```
doc.Achievement.indexOf(achievementId) == -1
```

Example condition in the if statement:

```
var condition = "doc.Score == 100"
```

Javascript will allow this code but will always return true. Is it possible to make JS read the String as a if statement?

Comment: JavaScript execution should be a last resort when all else fails. Chances are there is something else that can be used that actually solves you problem. Please show some sample data and desired result to clarify your question.

Comment: The condition can only be entered on a website that is password protected, only admins can enter this website. My use case accepts the risk of SQL injection by admins (they already have access to the MongoDB). The answer given by jAndy is enough for now.

Comment: You should have added what you are actually doing to your question rather than just accept the JavaScript solution. But if you cannot accept the truth of that then I'll see you later when you ask why you application is performing so badly. High Rep core != Correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only choice to accomplish that is the use of `eval()`, which pretty much does what it says. It evaluates a string of code.

```
if(eval(condition) && doc.Achievement.indexOf(achievementId) == -1) {
}
```

Comment: I seriously hope that `eval()` is not the only way out. Doesn't even seem so as there are probably other horrible JavaScript execution options available, that are not so horrible as `eval()`. Let us hope the OP actually provides a use case and example that suits a real answer to their problem.

Comment: @NeilLunn Well, there might be "other options", but as the OP asked the question, in this specific instance, `eval()` is the way to go.

Comment: Nope. This is JavaScript specific and does not answer the "MongoDB" question. There **are** other options.

Comment: No question about it. However, I answered the question how he can evaluate a string of code, which represents a condition, in Javascript. I don't felt compelled to analyze the whole application and offer other solutions. Nevermind.